# selecting certain rows in a data frame

Tags: r

I like to retrieve rows that meet some criteria. for example, from the below set up numbers, I like to retrieve rows Percent_free < 10. How would I do this in R?

```
 Date             file                 Percent_free
2011-12-06            /tmp             2
2011-12-06            /var             9
2011-12-06            /crash           11
```

Comment: start by reading the excellent R manuals: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html

Answer (score 7):

if your data is in a `data.frame` df:

```
df[df$Percent_free < 10,]
```

But, its worth giving the R-intro that Andrie linked a read.